# Flow through a cylinder with pores

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm building a model to study the flow of fluid through a cylinder with pores on its surface.

For flow through a cylinder, the velocity of the fluid flow is given by the Hagen-Poiseuille equation.

I would like to ask for suggestions on references from which I can look at derivations for a cylinder with porous walls.
By porous, I mean openings on the surface of the cylinder. Example, the pores present in the fenestrated capillary.

Comment: What's the typical size of pores?

Comment: Have you tried formulating a model on your own?

Comment: @Deep The size of the pore is 6-12 nm.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I tried procceeding this way, considering the pores to be positioned at equal distance.I am not sure how the pressure drop can be accounted for, as the flow of fluid through these pores will decrease the pressure. In a cylinder, without pores, the average velocity of the fluid can be computed from the Hagen-Poiseuille equation. Likewise, I am trying to compute the average velocity of the fluid along the axial direction of the cylinder and also the average velocity through the pore.

Answer (score 1):

Let Q(z) be the volumetric flow rate along the tube.  Then, from a mass balance on the flow, $$\frac{dQ}{dz}=-\pi D q\tag{1}$$where q(z) is the superficial flow velocity through (i.e., normal to) the porous  wall at location z.  From Darcy's law, q is related to the pressure difference between inside and outside of the tube P(z) by $$q=\frac{k}{\mu}\frac{P}{w}\tag{2}$$where w is the wall thickness, k is the permeability of the porous medium, and $\mu$ is the fluid viscosity.  Combining Eqns. 1 and 2 gives:
$$\frac{dQ}{dz}=-\frac{\pi Dk}{\mu w}P\tag{3}$$
From the Hagen-Poiseuille equation, $$\frac{dP}{dz}=-\frac{128\mu}{\pi D^4}Q\tag{4}$$
Eqns. 3 and 4 provide two coupled linear ordinary differential equations for the variations in pressure and volumetric flow rate along the tube.  You can eliminate P between these equations to solve for Q(z), and then use that to determine P.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. The cylinder that I am considering has pores only on its walls.The channel isn't filled with a porous medium. I think in that case the superficial velocity will not come into play.

Comment: My answer solves that case you are describing... the cylinder has pores only in its walls.  The channel isn't filled with a porous medium.  The superficial velocity represents the volumetric flow rate per unit area  normal to the wall.  I can't see how that all wasn't clear to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Since the post mentioned `porous medium`,I got confused. Apologies

Comment: You did say that the wall of the cylinder has pores (is porous), correct?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I got confused because I have learned these terminologies, `porous media` and `superficial velocity`, in the context of flow through packed beds, in the past.I failed to understand that porous medium, in this context, refers to the tiny openings in the wall of the cylinder.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if Hagen-Poiseuille formula would apply here given that we don't have the usual no-slip boundary and instead there is a (small) flow normal to porous pipe walls. But given that the flow is laminar, pressure drop must still be proportional to $Q$ with a prefactor different from that in H-P formula.

Comment: In the Hagen-Poiseuille formula, the velocity along z ,$v_z$ is a function of radius,r. When there are pores in the wall, the velocity along z will be a function of both z and r

Comment: That is correct.  So, can you figure out from my analysis how to express the axial velocity as a function of z and r?

Comment: @Deep What's the axial component of velocity at the pipe wall (given the size of the pores)?  But, the HP is definitely an approximation for another reason:  the average axial flow velocity is changing with z, and, as a result, there is a small radial component of velocity which builds up towards the wall of the pipe.

Comment: Depends on the inclination of the pore hole at a given point on the wall, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChesterMiller With inputs received from these discussions, I will proceed and update here soon.